# Linksys WMP54GS-EU wireless card not detected

Tags: 11.04, wireless-access-point

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my PC but Wireless Card Linksys WMP54GS-EU is not detected.
It says "there is no firmware".

On `System - Administration - Extra Drivers` I found only the Video Card drive which I regularly downloaded.

External software sources are duly enabled on Synaptic - Repository.

---

OK I find the solution: I downloaded from Ubuntu Software Center the Repository "b43-fwcutter" detected from Terminal (`lspci`).

Comment: welcome to AskUbuntu - well done for finding a solution.  Please add this as an answer - in a few hours after posting you will be able to accept it.  By doing so will allow us to up-vote you so that you can gain "rep".

Answer (score 1):

(Since the OP has not logged in since Oct 21 '11 but reported an answer I post that as an answer to close this question.)

By issuing the following in a terminal you can detect what the device is called:

```
lspci
```

What you need to do is to install the utility for extracting the firmware for your wireless card. Do this by issuing the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```